# Can I use a preposition followed by "next"?

Tags: prepositions

As an example

> Where do you want see you in next 5 years .

Is it correct? Are there any rules regarding the use of prepositions? If anyone knows please be kind enough to attach related links.

Comment: By the way, "you" as the object of a verb when "you" is the subject is so unusual that people are likely to be confused. Say "where do you want to see _yourself_".

Comment: Thank you colin for reply,i have one thing to get cleared ,is it possible to use "in" +"next" to be specific like "in next 5 months"

Comment: @Masterpiece.beta The definite article is necessary in the form you mention: _..in **the** next 5 months.._

Comment: Probably "Where do you see yourself in 5 years" is what is intended [Ob. xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1088/)

Answer (score 1):

"The + next/last + a number + plural periods" is a very common form of expression, and can be used anywhere a noun phrase would be expected:

Subject:

> The next two weeks are going to be difficult.

Object:

> I hated the last three months.

After a preposition:

> I will call on you in the next three days.

(meaning "at some time during the next three days").

'The' is required in this construction.

If the period is singular, don't use 'the'; and the expression can also be used as an adverbial:

> Last week was horrible.
>
> I'll go there next month.